# Add to Cart not working opencart mobile site

Tags: php, mobile, opencart2.x

My 'add to cart' is not working on mobile. When I open my site in my pc, add to cart work fine, but when I open it in my mobile it's not working.

I am using opencart 2.0.0.0. My site is http://www.webfrance.design/

Comment: Would you add into your question an example of what doesn't work that does not involve an external link? The problem with pointing to the live site is that once you have fixed it, the question won't make a lot of sense to new readers.

Comment: When you add some product to the cart and then you consult the cart is always emplty. this is the problem.

Comment: What mobile device are you using? Does the same happen with a device emulator?

Comment: I'm using samsung and iphone.

Answer (score 0):

Add to cart is working although your button get `hidden` by `CSS`

Change Below media query from below css file :  **Line no: 61**

http://www.webfrance.design/catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/stylesheet.css

```
span.hidden-xs, span.hidden-sm, span.hidden-md, span.hidden-lg {
    display: inline; 
}
```

To

```
span.hidden-xs, span.hidden-sm, span.hidden-md, span.hidden-lg {
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) but the problem it not solved. When you consult the cart is always emplty.

Comment: @RaniaKhlif have you successfully add items to cart?

Comment: No If you try to add items to cart and you consult the cart, it empty so I can't order.